# reading file line by line , modify the line and write this line on same file. Python

Tags: python, file, file-io

I've tried to read a file line by line and for each line that I read ,I tried to split it and after that I wanted to write it on where I got it. In order to do that I wrote such a code :

```
fst_file=open(fst_text,"r+")
    line=fst_file.readline()

    while line:
        temp=(line.split('CONFIG_',1)[1]).split('PATH=')
        temp[1]=temp[1].replace('\n','')
        fst_file.write(temp)        
        line=fst_file.readline()

    fst_file.close()
```

However I got an error like :

```
File "test.py", line 84, in <module>
    branchName()
  File "test.py", line 75, in branchName
    fst_file.write(temp)        
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

is there anybody to help me ?

Comment: You *cannot* rewrite specific lines in a file. If the line you write is longer then you'll overwrite the beginning of the next line, if it is shorter then you'll leave some junk. You must overwrite a line with another line that has *exactly* the same length. Also you cannot remove a line. Simply re-write the whole file. (also note that in your example code you are *not* rewriting over the line you just read. You are overwriting the *following* line; you'd end up losing half of the file like that).

Comment: @Bakuriu what do is mean re-write ?

Comment: Yes. I mean, cancel completely the contents of the file and rewrite them from the start. Files aren't made for modifying them in the middle.

Comment: @Bakuriu thanks for info. Now , my problem is changed. How could I store the lines that I read ?

Comment: One way is to read the whole file into memory, then process each line and put it into a list, and finally rewrite the file line by line. Otherwise you could open the file in reading mode and a second, *different* file, in writing mode, read one line, process it and write it in the second file. Finally when the process ends you can delete the file you read and renamed the other file.

Comment: I suggest you consider using the `fileinput.FileInput` class in the [`fileimput`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html?highlight=fileinput#module-fileinput) module which allows optional in-place filtering of the file(s) being read. This makes it possible to write a filter that rewrites its input file in place.

Answer (score 1):

Because you've used `.split` on the line, you're working with a list of strings. While a string is conceptually just a list of characters, it's still not a list of strings.

Try using the .join method of a string to join your array before you write it out, for example:

> ''.join(["one, two"]) == "onetwo"

Comment: thanks for comment. Is there any way to write it in a file "[one,two]" ?

Comment: Consider `"[%s]" % (','.join(["one", "two"]))`